# Increment headding level of entire section in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm using the headings to create sections in an outline format. I've created a large document, but now realized that one section actually needs to be nested in new section. How do I "indent" the whole section by incrementing heading level for all markdown cells within a section? Is there a way to do the reverse as well?

For example, the outline looks like this:

- Section 1

  - Topic A
  - Topic B

I want to turn it into this:

- Section 1

  - Topic C

    - Topic A
    - Topic B

Without having to do a tedious and unreliable find/replace, etc. on the whole document when there are many sections and many layers of nesting

Comment: You want to add a list?
Bullet point can force the indent like you want.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: No, not add lists. Want to change existing heading cells

Comment: Ahh I see well the bullet point in your example through me off, sorry about that.  Hopefully someone has an answer for you.

Comment: If it is really consistent, you can use nbformat to programmatically iterate on all the markdown cells in the notebook file and change the levels in a new notebook file the code could produce. See the last roughly 13 lines of the code in the code block [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/apply-sentence-case-in-jupyter-notebook-markdown-cells/7243/2?u=fomightez) for an outline of much of the code you'd need. You'd need to adapt the indented section below `if cell.cell_type == "markdown":` to handle what you need though.